# Angular Universal - Title is not seen in View Source but can be seen during Inspect

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have Angular 7 application with server side rendering using Angular Universal. (mainly followed tutorial https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-universal/)

Currently code is deployed and running on nodejs (4000 - with reverse proxy using apache2 server so that I can use port 80 - mentioning this in case this matters).

Inside my component (all my components are deeply nested), I am using code as below

```
....
constructor(private title: Title){}
....

ngOnInit() {
   this.title.setTitle('my title')
}
```

Please check (http://public.ecokrypt.com). If I click on 'Dashboard' I do see title changed on my browser. I also see the new title with 'Inspect'. But if I try 'View Source' it does not show me the new title. It always shows me the data from my first default page (login => title 'User'). Please not that my index.html contains 'EcokryptUiapp' as title, my first default login page contains 'User' as title. So first time it does render from server.

It seems after my first page, I never get any server side rendering. The same issue is with facebook/twitter meta tags as well.Due to this, if I try to debug facebook link / verify the twitter card, it gives me error.

I verified on my local development environment as well, view source always gives me first page, content never gets changed.

Am I missing any step ? I am stuck on this for last 3 days, just unable to find any solution. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of trial errors, I found the issue. Some where deep inside my code, I was using windows location and was getting error at server side due to the same. So after first default page nothing was getting rendered from server. Everything was getting evaluated at browser side only.

Hope someone might find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the title of your Angular project during inspect, but not in the view source, it is likely that the title is being set dynamically through JavaScript or Angular code. The view source only displays the static HTML that is initially loaded by the browser, whereas the title that is visible during inspect is being set by JavaScript or Angular after the page has loaded.

This is a common practice in modern web development, where the title is set dynamically based on the content being displayed or other factors. Search engines and social media platforms can still access and read the title even if it is set dynamically, so there is no need to worry about it affecting your website's SEO or social media sharing.

If you want to ensure that the title is visible in the view source, you can set it in the static HTML file or use Angular's meta service to set it dynamically.